# No properties option in Index context menu

Tags: sql-server, index

I am attempting to analyze the indexes of several of my tables according to a Microsoft article that [describes Reorganizing and Rebuilding Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes). The article says to right-click on the index within SSMS and then select properties. However, I don't see any option for properties on the right-click menu. I am using SSMS v17.1 with an Azure SQL Server v12.0.2000.8 (which I believe is SQL Server 2014).

[image]

Comment: SSMS lacks a few features in comparison to an In-Premise sql server db. They've improving a lot, but apparently, you still can't see those properties. You'll have to execute a query to see those values.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available for Azure yet.
You have to use `INDEXPROPERTY`.  Explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/indexproperty-transact-sql) with example for Azure.

On a side note Azure SQL Server v12.0.2000.8 is not SQL Server 2014. You cannot compare versions between Azure and On-premises.  Rather you should compare features if you have to.